# How to include an input text as an option inside chosen-select bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have question about the bootstrap chosen-select class.
Is it possible to add an input box as one of the option available for the user to select?

For example something like

```
 <option>burger<input type='text' value='1' name='eat_kg'/> </option>
```

if not, what is the best select option that i can use?

I will need to the user be able to select more than 1 option.

Comment: How about multiple select? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Comment: multiple select will need the user to press the ctrl/shift button to select multiple option, which I don't want to do that, as it easy for the user to wrongly select, or maybe accidentally let go of the ctrl/shift while selecting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do what you want to do. According to [HTML DOM Standards](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-option-element), only text is permitted to be placed within the `<option>` tag.

Escaped characters are also able to be used.

Your alternative could be to use Bootstrap dropdown and use radio boxes and input boxes beside eachother, so if a user selects a particular radio, get the corresponding input box.

Comment: Oh i see. I will have to think of another way then. The alternative you suggest is a good choice, but it will not be very pretty i think. Thanks though